# Return a date with Find

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a value in another sheet and return the row number so the adjacent cell can be filled with a string.

`FindWor`" is returning blank. The `.Find(what:=Findrng)` shows as 14/01/17 when I run and hover over that part.

If I change `Findrng` to a word such as "Home" and enter this on the file the code returns the correct row number so the problem must be with the date.

How can I use `.Find` for dates?

```vb
Private Sub Enter_Click()
Dim FindWor As Range
Dim Findrng As String
Dim FindRowNumber As Long

Findrng = Me.Date1
With Worksheets("Data").Range("$A:$A")
    Set FindWor = .Find(what:=Findrng)
    FindRowNumber = FindWor.Row
    .Cells(FindRowNumber, 2).Value = Me.Event1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont understand what is your problem but you could change your variable name Find..

Comment: I have edited the info, my problem is the findrow is blank when running the code. When I come out of VBA and manually try to find the info it is already populated in the find box. Could it be an issue with the date? Column A of the data tab is basically 2 years of dates starting from 01/01/17

Comment: Try `Set FindWor = .Find(what:=Find)`. Also, I suggest not using `Find` as a variable name, since it's a function in Excel, use something like `findRng`...

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I have made changes to the code which is now running but it is enterin the value in the next row after the last column, does anyone have any thoughts on this part?
`Private Sub Enter_Click()

Dim FindWor As Range
Dim Findrng As String
Dim FindRowNumber As Long



Find = Format(Me.Date1, "DD/MM/YYYY")
With Worksheets("Data").Range("$A:$A")
Set FindWor = .Find(what:=Findrng)
FindRowNumber = FindWor.Row

.Cells(FindRowNumber, 2).Value = Me.Event1
End With


End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

```
Set FindWor = .Find(what:=Findrng)
```

Findrng is a string ,and the data there is date , so it will definitely return nothing.

If you are not sure what will your code search weather string or date , first find the value as string , if not found convert it to date and do a search again

```
    Set FindWor = .Find(what:=Findrng)

    if  FindWor  is nothing  then
           Set FindWor = .Find(what:=cdate(Findrng))
    end if
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Working now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The `Find` method has a number of optional arguments, that don't have predefined defaults, but rather, they default to the values that were last used, either through code, or through the Excel user interface. **You should explicitly state all of the arguments in order to get consistent and expected behavior**.

The `Range.Find` method is defined as:

`Function Find(What, Optional After, Optional LookIn, Optional LookAt, Optional SearchOrder, Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, Optional MatchCase, Optional MatchByte, Optional SearchFormat) As Range`

You need to provide values for *all* of those arguments, even though they're marked as `Optional`

The `Find` method can also return a `Nothing` reference if a match cannot be found, so you need to test for `Nothing` before inspecting the `Row` property. For example:

```
Set FindRow = .Find(Find)
If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then
    FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
End If
```

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand what you mean. I have added a format to my text that I am looking to find, will this help? I can add in some code to return a comment box i no value is found. I hadn't thought of that so thanks.

Comment: Hi @ThunderFrame, I have changed my code to include the optional details but this brought more issues, I think this was due to the Optional After as I am not starting on the sheet that I am wanting to search on but I am searching from a User Form. My main issue looks to be around the fact that I am searching for a date as the code above works for a "Word". Can you recommend anything for searching for dates?

Answer (score 1):

You must `Dim` FindRowNumber as **Long**

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 sheets, both with concatenated strings for lookup values, and .Find only worked on these once I specified the LookIn:=xlValues option.